# Proper way to use StreamProvider with Pagination using Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented chat with pagination using StreamProvider, it was working fine. However, I have a concern about the cost and mind if I have implemented correctly because I am not using `startAfter` method and only using limits.

Here is my code:

```
 int documentLimit = 20;
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
          child: Consumer<ChatProvider>(builder: (context, chatProvider, child) {
            bool isFirstSender = true;
            if (chatProvider.selectedChatModel != null) {
              isFirstSender = chatProvider.selectedChatModel.uids[0] == user.uuid;
            }

            return Scaffold(
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                appBar: ApplicationBar.getChatAppBar(context,
                    userId: chatProvider.selectedChatModel.targetId),
                body: StreamProvider<ChatModel>.value(
                    catchError: (context, object) {
                      print(object);
                      return;
                    },
                    value: Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .streamChatDetail(
                            chatProvider.selectedChatModel.id, isFirstSender),
                    child: StreamProvider<List<MessageModel>>.value(
                      value: Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false)
                          .streamMessages(chatProvider.selectedChatModel.id,
                              isFirstSender, documentLimit),
                      child: ... /// The content
```

Then I have the scroll listener like this:

```
 _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      if (maxScroll == currentScroll) {
        setState(() {
          documentLimit = documentLimit + 20;
        });
      }
    });
```

This is the stream:

```
Stream<List<MessageModel>> getMessages(
      String uid, bool isFirstSender, int documentLimit) {
    if (uid != null && uid.isNotEmpty) {
      final DocumentReference documentReference =
          Firestore.instance.collection('user_chats').document(uid);
      Query chatDetailQuery = documentReference
          .collection("chats")
          .orderBy("date", descending: true)
          .reference()
          .limit(documentLimit);

      Stream<QuerySnapshot> chatSnapshots = chatDetailQuery.snapshots();
      return chatSnapshots.map((listChats) => listChats.documents.map((doc) {
            MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel.fromJson(doc.data);
            return messageModel;
          }).toList());
    }
    return Stream.empty();
  }
```

My question is:

1. First, I have loaded the 20 chat message then scrolling to the top and reload 20 more chat messages. Total read transaction will be 40 or 60 (because 20 + 40)?
2. If the first question answer is 60, then how correctly to implement the pagination for the StreamProvider?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. While I can answer 1 and 2 in one go, #3 is quite different and should not be part of the same post.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the third question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore charges a document read if it needs to read the document on your behalf on the server. If disk caching is enabled (which it is by default on iOS and Android) the second time you read the same documents in the scenario you describe they will be coming from the local cache. In that case you won't be charged for these reads.